# Can the Raspberry Pi handle Serviio? If not, is there something equivalent that will work?

Tags: media-server

Currently I have Serviio running on my computer to serve media files to our TV. I'd like to run this from my Pi instead, is this going to work?

If not, is there another application that's comparable that will work?

Comment: Never heard of Serviio. Have you looked at Samba?

Comment: depends on if you have to 'transcode' on the fly. serving a file (.avi) to a device (TV) that supports the format should be no issues, but converting files to MPEG-2 would be too much. http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=7681&p=94269

Comment: @Jivings Serviio is another 'British' Open Source invention http://www.serviio.org/ Even Sony [UK] are using it [rebranded] under the name 'Homestream' http://www.sony.co.uk/hub/1237485339460 note at the very bottom below downloads - Built on the Serviio platform.

Comment: @Mapperz Any particular reason British needed 'quotes'? :-P

Comment: You can test serviio it with a Raspberry Pi and Cream emulator using QEMU - http://wiki.soslug.org/wiki/raspberry_pi_emulation (tweaks required)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Serviio [Downloads page](http://www.serviio.org/download):

> **Minimal requirements**
>
> - 512 MB of memory or more
> - 20 MB of disk space (plus additional space for storing library definition), when using transcoding make sure there is at least 1GB free (depending on the original file size)
> - Java 6 installed

From these, it looks like it *might* be possible to get it running on the Raspberry Pi, though it is certainly marginal. Also, it is probably only an option on newer 512MB Raspberry Pi's than with old 256MB devices.

I would suggest that you give it a go. It is possible that the Raspberry Pi will be fast enough to run it without a decent [JIT compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), though hopefully we will get that eventually too.

You will also almost certainly need to need to compile or install your own copies of FFmpeg, libRTMP 2.4 and the Lame MP3 Encoder (v. 3.98).

Comment: Java? Unfortunately there are issues with Java on the Pi. There is not JIT compiler for ARM so execution is slow.